# Android memory spiking

Tags: android, memory, nexus-s

To start, thanks for taking the time to look over my question. I am currently having problems with memory spiking in the application I am developing.

My intent is to be able to download and process large amounts of HTML data, currently the cause is from large base64 encoded images nested in the HTML which I understand is not ideal for use on a mobile platform. For the record, I am currently testing on a Samsung Galaxy S. Also, this problem does **not** occur on the Galaxy Nexus due to more memory allocation per application.

My problem is that while processing a large chunk of HTML data of approximately 2.8mb, the memory heap increases to around 27-29mb but the allocated memory never passes beyond 18-19mb. When the HTML has been processed, saved and displayed the allocated memory returns to around 3-4mb. If I was to then download and process this HTML again, the process repeats and I get the same memory use, except it **seems** to increase the heap further (which to me doesn't seem necessary), at this point I receive an `Out of memory` error.

When I do receive this error it is normally while downloading the HTML  using `HttpGet` or while extracting the data from disk using a `StringBuffer`. Occasionally it is caused by a `Bitmap` during an XML inflation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Galaxy S has 2.3 running, right? So you compare Gingerbread with ICS. You should try to clean up after your parsing as best as possible...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The Galaxy S is 2.3.6. I am cleaning up as much as I can, I'm just curious as to why the allocated memory never surpasses 18mb but it still tries to extend the heap...

Comment: Please post the LogCat output produced for the garbage collections and the failing final allocation.

Answer (score 0):

There is little you can do if you really need that amount of memory. Phones have limited memory.

Dealocating memory is not instantaneous. It might take several iterations to free all the memory (and each iteration might be executed a few seconds apart).

It's frequent to have problems with too much memory used by images/drawables. Some times it's a memory leak; other times it's not possible to say what is causing it.

I've also had problems parsing large xml files. My solution was spliting those files into smaller ones. Another possibility is considering the advantages and disadvantages of different xml parsers (first google result: [SAX parser vs XML pull parser](http://www.firstobject.com/xml-reader-sax-vs-xml-pull-parser.htm)). Maybe using some thirdparty implementation specially developed with memory usage concerns? One third option is using a server to convert the xml file to a more efficient format.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Pedro, I will have a look for third party libraries later. I am currently parsing HTML from JSON data, but I can't seem to get round the memory spiking for larger data chunks.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is not to allocate lots of memory. Process the data in-stream as you're reading it from the network, or stream it to disk and then read from there. The android:largeHeap option is available on all devices running Android 3.0 or above, but that only increases the amount you can allocate not remove the limit altogether.